# Django Relational managers

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-rest-framework

I was trying to delete my Apllication model:

```
class Application(models.Model):
    app_type = models.ForeignKey(ApplicationCategory, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='applications')
    fio = models.CharField(max_length=40)
    phone_number = models.CharField(max_length=90)
    organisation_name = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True, blank=True)
    aid_amount = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    pay_type = models.CharField(max_length=1, choices=PAY_CHOICES, default=PAY_CHOICES[0][0])
    status = models.ForeignKey(AppStatus, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='applications', null=True, blank=True)
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    benefactor = models.ForeignKey(Benefactor, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='applications', null=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return f"id={self.id} li {self.fio} ning mablag\'i!"
```

and this was my Benefactor model:

```
class Benefactor(models.Model):
    fio = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    phone_number = models.CharField(max_length=9)
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='media/')
    sponsory_money = models.IntegerField()
    organisation_name = models.CharField(max_length=55, null=True, blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return f"{self.fio}"
```

But I got the below message on superAdmin Panel:

```bash
TypeError at /admin/api/benefactor/

create_reverse_many_to_one_manager.\<locals\>.RelatedManager.__call__() missing 1 required keyword-only argument: 'manager'
```

I would expect delete smoothly!!

Answer (score 0):

Your `Benefactor` model has several `ForeignKey` relationships that share the `related_name`. Give each a unique name and rerun your migrations.